# why is java showing MAXRAM to 128gb

Tags: java

I only have 16Gb Ram, but as shown below, java is showing MAXRAM to 128 Gb, even though it is accurately calculating MaxHeapSize to be 4Gb (25% of 16 Gb)

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -Ei "maxheapsize|maxram"
 size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4294967296                                
 {product} {ergonomic}
 uint64_t MaxRAM                                   = 137438953472                           
 {pd product} {default}
 uintx MaxRAMFraction                           = 4                                         
 {product} {default}
 double MaxRAMPercentage                         = 25.000000                                 
 {product} {default}
 java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 2):

MaxRAM indicates total memory that can be used (overheads + heap). It includes virtual memory (on your disk) available for use.